# why windows forms timer stopped working?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# based application, I create a new form in my application which has its own System.Forms.Timer object. First time when I create the form everything works fine, i receive timer ticks, no issues. On certain condition, I have to kill the form and create a new (same) form object.  Form is created in similar manner. Form is loaded properly, timer is initialized properly but **timer does not tick**. I tried different approaches such as stop and disposing timer object and creating a new one in FormLoad but in vain. My friend suggested that probably my new form object does not receive Windows timer messages (WM_TIMER). How do I check if message loop is working fine in my new form object? What is it that i am doing incorrectly?

In short, recreating a form object disables timer ticks somehow.  Please advise.

Code is full of Reflection and spread out. I will try to post as much as i can.

*Code to create a new form object*

```
Form f = ReflectUtils.CreateClassFromAssembly( _TheAssembly, FormName ) as Form;
if ( null == f )
{
    throw new ApplicationException( "Failed to create Form: {");
}
_GUICancelEventHandler = new CancelEventHandler( GUIControlForm_Cancel );
f.Closing += _GUICancelEventHandler;

f.Show();
```

*Code to destroy form*

```
f.Close();
f.Dispose();
```

Application uses same code to create new form objects.

Designer code for timer

```
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
this.timer1.Interval = 500;
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

*inside formLoad event*

```
timer1.Start();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please show the code for what you have thus far.

Comment: I have added the code. Because of its implementation I am not sure how much helpful it will be. I guess I am just trying to understand a general behavior of windows forms timers, if there is something obvious that I am missing out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to kill your form, Its better to keep timers independent of your form instances.

I would suggest,

Instead of having your timer in your form, maintain timers in a separate class such that it will not be disposed with the form you are going to kill.

access the timers (start,stop,reset,handle events) using the object of that class.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could replace my Forms timer with `System.Timers.Timer` class object. Will try that out.

Comment: @Alok Not just replace, but as Bharath has said, move it out into its own class to be instantiated separately.  If it's still in the form, it dies with the form.

Comment: I am fine if it dies with the form as long as it is created properly when new form instance is created. I don't understand why timer won't work if a new timer object is created properly.

Comment: Think you forgot to enable the timer before starting it in the new instance. try including this in form_load before starting the timer. 'timer.Enabled = true'